# How to find 2 column values of one dataframe in another dataframe and replace the initial values if match found?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare two column values **[a]** & **[b]** of test dataframe with my master dataframe. If the match is found, I want to add values from column **[x]** & **[y]** from test data to master data.

If there are duplicates in master data for **[a]** & **[b]** , the resp. values in **[x]** & **[y]** need to be updated at all the rows.

If values are already present in **[x]** and **[y]** of master data, then they must be updated with those in test data.

If duplicate combination is present in test data during iteration, like combo **6545** in **[a]** and **345** in **[b]** is again found at last row, the initially updated value in master data must be replaced with latest one.

**Master Data:**

```
a1 = [['11A2',456,'c0','',''], ['16C3',523,'c1','',''], ['11A2',456,'c2','',''],['45CE',876,'c3',5,'13-03-2021'],[6545,342,'c4','',''],[8888,123,'c5',20,'21-02-2021'],['523V',654,'c6','','']]
master = pd.DataFrame(a1, columns=['a','b','c','x','y'])
```

```
    a       b   c   x   y
0   11A2    456 c0      
1   16C3    523 c1      
2   11A2    456 c2      
3   45CE    876 c3  5   13-03-2021
4   6545    342 c4      
5   8888    123 c5  20  21-02-2021
6   523V    654 c6
```

**Test Data:**

```
a2 = [[6545,342,25,'25-05-2021'], ['45CE',876,15,'19-04-2021'], ['11A2',456,40,'07-09-2021'],[4444,321,51,'26-12-2021'],[8888,123,50,'30-03-2021'],[6545,342,50,'15-07-2021']]
test = pd.DataFrame(a2, columns=['a','b','x','y'])
```

```
    a       b   x   y
0   6545    342 25  25-05-2021
1   45CE    876 15  19-04-2021
2   11A2    456 40  07-09-2021
3   4444    321 51  26-12-2021
4   8888    123 50  30-03-2021
5   6545    342 50  15-07-2021
```

**Final master data:**

```
    a       b   c   x   y
0   11A2    456 c0  40  07-09-2021
1   16C3    523 c1      
2   11A2    456 c2  40  07-09-2021
3   45CE    876 c3  15  19-04-2021
4   6545    342 c4  50  15-07-2021
5   8888    123 c5  50  30-03-2021
6   523V    654 c6
```

**What I tried:**
I have tried to map dataframes using merge, but due to presence of duplicates, getting error.
Even I tried by setting [a] and [b] as index and using join, but its not working for duplicate indices.

Do we need to iterate using loop in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can drop the duplicate rows in `test` with respect to columns `a, b` then set the index of `test` and `master` to `a, b` and **[`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)** the values in `master` using the values from `test`

```
c = ['a', 'b']
master = master.set_index(c)
master.update(test.drop_duplicates(c, keep='last').set_index(c))
master = master.reset_index()
```

---

```
      a    b   c     x           y
0  11A2  456  c0  40.0  07-09-2021
1  16C3  523  c1                  
2  11A2  456  c2  40.0  07-09-2021
3  45CE  876  c3  15.0  19-04-2021
4  6545  342  c4  50.0  15-07-2021
5  8888  123  c5  50.0  30-03-2021
6  523V  654  c6
```